# Django HiddenField value generated on Views

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

**Overview:** need to generate a codename value for a hidden field in order to send it to an external API (1) and after that include the generated codename field in database (2).

**Issue:** How can I send the generated codename (HiddenField) to database?

---

---

**models.py**

```
class Category(Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45)

class Animal(Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    codename = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = models.Category
        fields = '__all__'

class AnimalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    codename = serializers.HiddenField(default="auto_replace_me")

    class Meta:
        model = models.Animal
        fields = '__all__'
```

**views.py**

```
class CategoryViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Category.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.CategorySerializer


class AnimalViewSet(ModelViewSet, CreateModelMixin):

    queryset = models.Animal.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.AnimalSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        codename = generate_codename()

        # (1) external API request (with codename included on request) and returns a boolean `result`

        if result:

            # will call create method from parent class BUT
            # (2) it needs to save the codename in database

            return super(AnimalViewSet, self).create(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return HttpResponseServerError()


def generate_codename():
    return ''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for n in range(10)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code should do the job:

```
class AnimalViewSet(ModelViewSet, CreateModelMixin):

    queryset = models.Animal.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.AnimalSerializer

    def perform_create(serializer, codename):
        serializer.save(codename=codename)

    def create_with_codename(self, request, codename, *args, **kwargs):
        # this is almost the same as CreateModelMixin 'create' 
        # but with one change: passing codename to 'perform_create' method

        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        instance = self.perform_create(serializer, codename)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        codename = generate_codename()

        # (1) external API request (with codename included on request) and returns a boolean `result`

        if result:

            # will call create method from parent class BUT
            # (2) it needs to save the codename in database

            return self.create_with_codename(request, codename, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return HttpResponseServerError()
```

So basically, you should write your own function `create_with_codename` to change default behaviour of `CreateModelMixin` `def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs)`
Most important thing was to pass `codename` argument to `perform_create`. According to [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#passing-additional-attributes-to-save), everytime when you need to save serializer with appending additional values to it, you should use `serializer.save(extra_field=extra_value)`

Comment: `ModelViewSet` class is inherited from `CreateModelMixin` and other 5 classes

Comment: [Here you can see the SC](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/viewsets.py#L178)

Answer (score 0):

After learn from you guys, I got this solution (*only changing views.py*):

**views.py**

```
class CategoryViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Category.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.CategorySerializer


class AnimalViewSet(ModelViewSet, CreateModelMixin):

    queryset = models.Animal.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.AnimalSerializer

    codename = None

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(codename=self.codename)

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        self.codename = generate_codename()

        # (1) external API request (with codename included on request) and returns a boolean `result`

        if result:

            # will call create method from parent class BUT
            # (2) it needs to save the codename in database

            return super(AnimalViewSet, self).create(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return HttpResponseServerError()


def generate_codename():
    return ''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for n in range(10)])
```